# Run php function after html click after page refresh

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to create a table of custom type posts in the admin section, in my plugin's settings page. The part I'm having trouble with is allowing user's to delete a custom post through my table. 
What I have so far is

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['remove_now'])){//.$post_id
    custom_post_removal_func ($_GET['remove_now']);
    header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

    die();

    }
?>
<tr>
    <td width = '35%'><?php echo $the_title?></td>
    <td width = '20%'><?php echo $post_start?></td>
    <td width = '10%'><?php echo $run_time ?></td>
    <td width = '15%'><a href='./admin.php?page=plugin_settings_page&remove_now=<?php echo $custom_post_id?>'>Remove Now</a></td>
</tr>
```

When I click on the "remove now" link it takes me to a blank page and doesn't run the custom_post_removal_func function.
thanks

Comment: is this period a typo error in your code `href='./admin.php`?

Comment: it might be that the plugin builder blocked this to